# Printing all content of a JList as output

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I have a `JList` in my GUI, which uses an `ArrayList` as data:

```
    ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();
    Cruise.add("Scottish to Greek Waters");
    Cruise.add("Greek to Scottish Waters");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    CruiseList = new JList(Cruise.toArray()); 
    CruiseList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(CruiseList);
    CruiseList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    CruiseList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    CruiseList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
    listPanel.add(scrollPane);
    Frame1.setVisible(true);
```

I have a button - <kbd>List all Cruises</kbd>, which once clicked on should display this as output:

```
"Scottish to Greek Waters"
"Greek to Scottish Waters"
```

However, upon clicking the button, it only displays the **selected** list option as output.

This is what I have so far:

```
listallCruises.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String AllCruises = CruiseList.getSelectedValue().toString();
        System.out.print("All Cruises:\n" + AllCruises + CruiseList.getModel() + "\n");
    }
});
```

How do I print out all element in the list upon clicking the button?

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting just the selected value because that's the method you are calling, `getSelectedValue()`.

To display ALL the values, you have to get the model and iterate through the values, like so:

```
int size = CruiseList.getModel().getSize();
StringBuilder allCruises = new StringBuilder("All cruises:");
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    allCruises.append("\n").append(CruiseList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
}
System.out.print(allCruises);
```